# How to display Pending Count, Completed, Rejected, Total Count for Financial and Month Wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I want to display Counts for Pending, Completed, Rejected, Total based on Financial Year and Month Wise.

Example Financial Year : April to March

My Project contains Data from 2019-Jan-01.

I want output as attached Image.

[image: Expected Output Data]

If Next Month [May] comes then it should add to the table. Expected Output [Image 2 ] as attached.

[image: Expected Output Data]

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. There is more to it than "I want" with pictures of data.

Comment: What step are you having trouble with? Are you having trouble with coming up with the SQL statement or is you encountering some sort of error? What does the schema look like? We might be able to help with more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following table structure:

```
mytable
    mydate  datetime
    status  ('pending', 'completed', 'rejected')
```

You can offset the date by 3 month to generate the fiscal year, and do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    year(dateadd(month, -3, mydate)) fiscal_year,
    month(mydate) fiscal_month,
    sum(case when status = 'pending'   then 1 else 0 end) pending,
    sum(case when status = 'completed' then 1 else 0 end) completed,
    sum(case when status = 'rejected'  then 1 else 0 end) rejected,
    count(*) total
from mytable
group by year(dateadd(month, -3, mydate)), month(mydate)
order by fiscal_year, fiscal_month
```

This will, for example, put records from March 2019 to April 2020 in fiscal year 2019.

If you want the `fiscal_year` column as `'2019-2020'` instead, then you can replace `year(dateadd(month, -3, mydate))` with the following expression in the `select` clause and `group by` clauses:

```
cast(year(dateadd(month, -3, mydate)) as varchar(4)) 
+ '-' 
+ cast(year(dateadd(month, -3, mydate)) + 1 as varchar(4))
```

Comment: Thanks GMB for quick reply. I have edited my question and attached expected output. So please check once again and post your complete answer.
I'm new to Sql Server, Please explain clearly.

Comment: @Rummy: the query and the answer are complete. Please run it against your data and see the results it produces. You can search the internet for something like *sql conditional aggregation*.

Comment: i have framed below query and got expected output. But i want more effectively.

2018-2019 March, it should start with 2019-2020 April, 2019-2020 May, 2019-2020 June, 2019-2020 July ....so on.And then 2020-2021 April,2020-2021 May, 2020-2021 June...

So Please help on this.

Comment: Query:
select
    cast(year(dateadd(month, -3, Sugg_Date)) as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast(year(dateadd(month, -3, Sugg_Date)) + 1 as varchar(4)) as Financial_Year,
    month(Sugg_Date) as Month_No,DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(Sugg_Date) , -1 ) ) Month_Name,
    sum(case when Sugg_Created_By='lvrla-sup' and Sup_Status in ('Open','Submitted') and CI_Approval_Status in ('Open','Completed') and HOD_Approval_Status='Open'  then 1 else 0 end) Pending,

Comment: sum(case when Sugg_Created_By='lvrla-sup' and Sup_Status='Submitted' and CI_Approval_Status='Completed' and HOD_Approval_Status='Completed' then 1 else 0 end) Completed,
    sum(case when Sugg_Created_By='lvrla-sup' and Sup_Status='Submitted' and CI_Approval_Status in ('Completed','Rejected') and HOD_Approval_Status in ('Rejected','NA')  then 1 else 0 end) Rejected,
    sum(case when Sugg_Created_By='lvrla-sup' then 1 else 0 end) Total
from Suggestion_Details
group by year(dateadd(month, -3, Sugg_Date)), month(Sugg_Date)
order by Financial_Year,Month_No,Month_Name